# При создании файла json с ссылкой в названии выдает ошибку "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python-3.x, json, парсер

Я новичек в питоне и до этого момента я искал решения своих проблем сам, но тут у меня ступор...

При запуске на python3

```
import json
...
url = input("Введите ссылку на чат: ")
...
with open ('u{{users{0}}}.json'.format(url), 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(all_users_details, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Выдает мне се чудо

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'u{usershttps://t.me/joinchat/I...}.json'
```

Я пилю парсер чатов для того чтобы с пользой обучиться питону, нашел исходники на ГитХабе и решил модифицировать.

P.s Если что я не SMM'щик, сам презираю спам в лс или в чаты

Comment: Запрещённые символы в имени файла.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов возможно ли как-то это ограничение обойти? К примеру вырезать "https:..."?

Comment: Вы не указали, какая у Вас ОС, так что смотрите сами, какие в Вашей ОС запрещены символы в имени файла и решайте, что с ними делать. Я бы в качестве имени файла брал просто какой-то уникальный id пользователя.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов хорошо, благодарю